# (δ→φ)∧(φ→δ)⊣⊢(δ∨φ)→(δ∧φ)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I solved this exercice that I need to deliver today but I'm not really sure if the way I did it is correct.

I started by proving (δ→φ)∧(φ→δ)⊢(δ∨φ)→(δ∧φ) and then proving (δ∨φ)→(δ∧φ)⊢(δ→φ)∧(φ→δ) as you can see on the image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUUSv.jpg)

It would mean a lot if you can tell me if the way I did it is correct or not, thanks.

Comment: Could you write out the proof in the post? That way your question becomes more easily searchable and any answers might help other people.

Comment: I don't really have the time to do that right now because I have to deliver this work in a few hours and I don't really know how to format text here. I might do it when I have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first proof, on line 9 you refer to line 5, but that is not allowed, since line 5 is part of a subproof is closed off to line 9.

What you need to do is to do a proof by cases on the disjunction you have on line 2 ... Note that indeed you never used line 2 in your proof, which should strike you as pretty weird in the first place, since that is the antecedent of the conclusion: surely you would need to use that at some point!

So: on line 3, assume $\phi$, and using the left conditional from line 1, get $\psi$, and then conjunct the two to get $\phi \land \psi$. Then do a second subproof assuming $\psi$ and eventually get $\phi \land \psi$ as well, and then by v Elim you get $\phi \land \psi$ in the outside subproof.

The second proof is correct!

Comment: On line 14 I didn't mean to say that I used elimination of the implication on lines 9-13. I meant 9,13. That's why you said I couldn't use line 10 on line 14 right?

Comment: You're right ... That was just a notational error and not the same as what happend on Line 9 ... What you do on line 9 is really not allowed.

Comment: Could I use Repetition on line 4 instead of the implication and then use it on line 9?

Comment: @JoãoSilva so do you know what I meant by a proof by cases?  It is when you do a subproof on each of the disjuncts of the disjunction you have on line 2, and at the end of each subproof you try to get the same result (which will be the consequent of the conditional you are trying to prove), which you can then write down after the two subproofs by reference to the two subproofs and the disjunction. The rule is typically v Elim

Comment: No, what you did on line 4 is actually incorrect as well. You really just need to redo the whole proof with the exception of the outside subproof assumption and last line.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, you meant I need to do the elimination of the disjunction. But I'm not seeing how I can get the same result on the two subproofs.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I added the basic schema to my answer.  What you get in both cases is $\phi \land \psi$

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Basically I need to get ϕ∧ψ on each subproof. It should be like this https://i.gyazo.com/d803ee2ea0f373038fc700cb8d6aa4d0.jpg right?

Comment: Perfect!  I can tell you that you are doing pretty well with these proofs ... A few more of these and you will be cranking them out like a machine! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man!